# Kernel module blacklist not working

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-modules

I'm trying to figure out how to blacklist modules, and I'm trying it on the USB storage. Unfortunately it seems to have no effect, and I get the module in even if it's not used (apparently).

My experiment is taking place on an Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS.

```
raptor@raptor-VirtualBox:/etc/modprobe.d$ lsmod | grep usb
usb_storage            39720  0 
usbhid                 46054  0 
hid                    82511  2 hid_generic,usbhid
raptor@raptor-VirtualBox:/etc/modprobe.d$ cat blacklist.conf | grep usb
blacklist usb_storage
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your problem probably results from the fact that a copy of `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` is located in the initramfs. When you reboot your computer, it is still using the old copy that doesn't contain your change. Try to rebuild the initramfs with the following command and then reboot:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: Worked like charm

Comment: Yup. That did it.

Comment: Thank you! This saves me a lot of frustration!

Answer (score 0):

If `update-initframfs` doesn't exist, look for `/bin/kernel-install`.  If that exists, you'll need to use that.  On my Fedora system I did `rpm -q --scripts kernel-core` to find the post transaction (posttrans) scriptlet and ran it manually:

```
/bin/kernel-install add 5.5.5-200.fc31.x86_64 /lib/modules/5.5.5-200.fc31.x86_64/vmlinuz
```

Answer (score 0):

For system based on RHEL (suse/opensuse/etc.) to update the initramfs the command is

```
mkinitrd
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to regenerate your initrd for your currently active kernel on any Fedora/RHEL/CentOS/Rocky/Alma Linux distro is to simply run:

```
dracut -f
```

No need to mess with mkinitrd.